# Can I use MVC6 for razor as well as like Web API ?

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc, restful-architecture

I am about to develop one web portal with tight time constraint. My requirements are 
1. Web portal
2. Android and IPhone app.

Can I use MVC6 for both? Like controllers are returning Action results for my views and mobile app developers can use same controllers to get data into Jason format? 
If It's possible then what's the learning curve for it?

I am familiar with MVC5. Where I use typical MVC with razor view. Now in my team I have android, iPhone, and HTML CSS developers. So I want to write one core logic at my own others will consume it at UI level.

Answer (score 0):

I've no right to comment so I'm going to write my answer.
Which I suppose will work. one can use Razor and API Controllers in both MVC5 as well as in 6. Here is a post by Mike Brind which will help you through this. 
[Mike Brind Post Integrate API and razor](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/261/integrating-web-api-with-asp-net-razor-web-pages)